# Inequality $2x-3y<6$ graphing the inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a quick question about the following inequality

$2x-3y<6$

If I do this

$-3y<-2x+6$ and the divide by -3 I get

$y>\frac{2}{3}{x}-2$

then I shade in above the line,

But if I do

$2x-3y<6$

$3y<2x-6$
I get

$y<\frac{2}{3}x-2$

But then I would shade below the line but I think my algebra is correct on both?

Comment: How 2x-3y<6 implies 3y<2x-6?Is it wrong?

Comment: I am not sure It is something I noticed and caught my eye

Comment: Yes it is wrong, it should be reversed.

Comment: It is because you divide -6 by 3?

Comment: Consider this example: $ 1<2$ but $-1>-2$

Comment: 2x-3y<6 implies 3y>2x-6
But you have wriiten 3y<2y-6

Comment: Oh I see but how do you know it implies?

Comment: just taking 3y to the RHS of the inequality and bringing 6 to the LHS

Comment: Oh I see I feel really stupid now. Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome.sometime it happens..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2x-3y\lt 6\Rightarrow 2x-6\lt 3y\Rightarrow 3y\gt2x-6$ your mistake was to put $3y\lt 2x-6$.